# I think that is a misstake on all internet sites which a saw and in all books about java which i saw about the precedence table! (syntax misstake)

Tags: java

My friends, I am a c++, c, python and c# developer from china.
All Javabook and all Internet sites, which I saw in my own said, that the precedense in java are like the table under my text.
the precedence table says:
+expr and -expr is over additive + and - and also  over the multiplicative like *,/ and %.

for instance

`b*-a` would interpreted as `(b)*(-a)` and that is true okay and correct with the table.

But, when I follow the table

`a+b` should not work because,  the precedence table, which is in all books which i saw like in the internetsite, says Java should interpreted it so:

```
a(+b)
```

so we should get a error and not an addition, but java makes an addition between a and b, but normally that should not be a addition, when I follow the precedence table.

When i make a++b then java intepret at like the precedence table to a+(+b), but normally, when I follow the precedence table a addition like a+b should not work, because the precedence table says that is not a addition!

[precedence table a little bit of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tw8rv.png)

Comment: You can't write `a++b`, that results in a syntax error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site. You have not asked any question or explained what the problem is.

Comment: Yes because (a++)b dthat is true and correct with the precedence table, so that will not be work, but a+b should also not work, because the precedence table said that we need to interpret it like a(+b)

Comment: but a+++b should not be a problem, but it is a problem, when I follow the precedence table!

Comment: The precedence table describe the evaluation order of an expression, not how the source code is parsed by the lexer.

Comment: You might want to check other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36061185/java-expression-interpretation-rules-of-decrement-increment-operators

Comment: The Problem is the precedence table says when I have a + and a expr. that this + is in connection with the expression so it should be a+b not a+b it should be a(+b) the + should not be a addition, it should be a parameter for the b! And the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36061185/java-expression-interpretation-rules-of-decrement-increment-operators is also a misstake! Like this articel a+b should be interpeted as a(+b) and not as a addition!

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a question your want to ask.

Comment: Either all books and web sites in the world are wrong, or you are wrong.  Which do you think?

Comment: A precedence table is used to disambiguate a parse for an ambiguous grammar or to help write a grammar that is not ambiguous. The precedence table is not a grammar for Java expressions. Starting with the [Language Spec grammar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-19.html), or [the Antlr instantiation of the grammar from the Language Spec](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/java/java9), it is impossible to produce a parse tree remotely similar to "a (+b)" (ignoring most of the intermediate CST node for expressions) for input "a+b".

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that 'unary plus' and 'binary plus' are **different operators** that happen to use the same character in source code.

So, first of all, it is necessary to determine whether a given '+' is the unary plus operator or the binary plus operator.  **Only after that** do you worry about precedence.

The presentation of syntax in the Java language spec should make it clear.  Given that we are in a context that requires an 'expression' and that we have 'a+b', we can't start the syntactical analysis in the middle of the expression and decide that '+b' is a unary expression, ignoring the previous characters. Instead, we parse left-to-right, recognize 'a+b' as an additive expression (in which 'a' and 'b' are each multiplicative expressions, and in turn are each unary expressions, according to the written grammar).